# How can I prove that I can assume $\sin{x}, \tan{x}$ to be x when $x \rightarrow 0$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I know the proof of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}=1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\tan{x}}{x}}=1$.

However, I do not think that this means that I can change every  $\sin{x}$ and $\tan{x}$ inside a limit to x and solve the problem, because the rule of limits can only be apllied if both limits exist, and it also does not mention anything about composite functions (for example $\sin{(\sin{(x)})}$)

Is it possible to prove that every $\sin(x)$ and $\tan(x)$ can be canged into x no matter its location if $x\rightarrow 0$ **Without Taylor Expansion**

Comment: Those limits in your question do not tell you that $\sin x$ etc can be replaced by $x$ but they rather tell you that $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x} {x} $ can be replaced by $1$. You should understand that this is fundamentally different from assuming $\dfrac{\sin x} {x} =1$. Also the genesis of such ideas (that limit equations should imply or justify the replacement of $\sin x$ by $x$) is totally mysterious for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be proven, because it's not true. For example:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}$$
While
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x^3}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

See Taylor expansion of these functions : you can say that near $0$, they "look like" a polynomial and control the difference.

For example, $\sin x = x + x\cdot \varepsilon(x)$ where $\varepsilon$ is a continuous function of $x$ vanishing at $0$.

Comment: Actually we haven't learned taylor expansion yet, so I need an alternative solution. Edited question.

Comment: Did you learn about the equivalence $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x) = a \iff \exists \varepsilon$ continuous and vanishing at $0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+h) =f(x) +  a(x+h) + x\varepsilon(h)$ ?